# Is there any way to use class and title in Selenium IDE

Tags: html, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

So, I tried using XPath, but that keeps changing, and I tried using CSS, but for some reason, the `click` doesn't work. What I want to do is click on an element. I have the Class and Title of this element, as well as the Class of the parent div. FirePath gives me a different XPath every time, so I can't use that.
Class of div ='`dhtmlx_wins_btns_button dhtmlx_button_close_default`'
Title of div = '`Close`'
Class of parent = '`dhtmlx_wins_btns`'
I tried to do this:
`//[@class='dhtmlx_wins_btns_button dhtmlx_button_close_default' and @class='Close']`
but that didn't work. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.
*****EDIT*****
Sorry for the confusion, I seem to be doing too many things at once.
I also tried to do:
`//[@class='dhtmlx_wins_btns_button dhtmlx_button_close_default']`
and
`//[@title=Close]`
but that didn't work. Although, clicking the ***Find*** button in  IDE highlights the item. Same goes for the CSS. I was hoping if I placed the 2 together, it would work.
I thought there were multiple divs with the same class, but I could have been looking at something else. Whoever named them has used far too similar names for the classes.
Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: Didn't work how? Was it found at all or did the click still not happen? Post the HTML of that div as well as another similar one (i.e you said there are multiple div's with the same class, so we'll need to see what is the difference)

Comment: @Arran For when I tried to use both class and title, it stated: `[error] locator not found: //div[@...`  
With the CSS, it was found, as when I click on the __Find__ button in Selenium IDE it highlights the element, but when I execute the command, it doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: In your edit, `//[@='dhtmlx_wins_btns_button dhtmlx_button_close_default']` is actually invalid XPath but I am going to assume that's a typo? Need to see a copy of your page. Also what CSS selector did you use?

Comment: @Arran Sorry, Chrome keeps remove Class and div and Selenium whenever I go to the edit

Comment: @Arran This is the CSS: `css=div.dhtmlx_wins_btns_button.dhtmlx_button_close_default` which does not return any errors, and also when I click _Find_ in Selenium it does highlight it.  
I'll see if I can get a screenshot uploaded to you by Monday morning.

Comment: @Arran ![Image](http://s21.postimg.org/mtkenfa6v/Screen2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is not correctly formatted.

a). Try this XPath in which conditions is correctly formatted with both class & title.

```
//div[@class='dhtmlx_wins_btns_button dhtmlx_button_close_default' and @title='Close']
```

b). Try this only if the first is not working and here I have considered the parent tag as a div

```
//div[@class='dhtmlx_wins_btns'/div[@class='dhtmlx_wins_btns_button dhtmlx_button_close_default' and @title='Close']
```

Comment: I tried both. The first one finds the element, but doesn't click it, however if I change the Command from `click` to `mouseDown` or `mouseUp` or `mouseOver` it does what it is supposed to. The second one gives me the error _invalid XPath_ when I execute the Command, but when I click Find, it gives the error _locator  not found_.

Comment: Div acts as a container to place other objects inside it. Can you check if you have any child for your Div - class='dhtmlx_wins_btns_button dhtmlx_button_close_default'. If its a Button that you are trying to click then under your <Div> tag there will be an <input> tag as child.

Comment: There is nothing inside the second div. In the parent div, there are other div's inside it, but none inside the div with _class=dhtmlx_wins_btns_button dhtmlx_button_close_default_. The div does click a close button on an upload file, but as you can see: ![IMAGE](http://s21.postimg.org/mtkenfa6v/Screen2.png)  
The close is not a generic, built-in window, otherwise I could've tried to use `Close`

Comment: Okay, I tried a website in public domain with similar scenario. It just work for me without much trouble, try simple way only mentioning class like //div[@class='dhtmlx_wins_btns_button dhtmlx_button_close_default' ]

Comment: As stated earlier, when I do Class alone, it highlights the element when I click the **Find** button in Selenium IDE, however, when I execute it, nothing appears to happen. No errors are returned, and it hasn't clicked either. And the same thing happens when I do `//div[@title='Close']`.

Comment: As a last try, can use the following, "Command:" clickAt "Target:" //div[@class='dhtmlx_wins_btns_button dhtmlx_button_close_default' and @title='Close'] "Value:" 1,1